# Mysql useServerPrepStmts affects the precision of queried float value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, precision

In our application recently we had to change the Mysql connection param `useServerPrepStmts` from `true` to `false` for various reason.

After the change, we found that, this started affecting the precision of the value of `float` columns queried from DB. When the param was `true`, we were exactly getting what we were setting. After it is set to `false`, the float values are rounded off to 5 digits.

Any idea why is this happening and what's the right way to fix it?

Comment: `float` is an approximate numeric data type all the time, so you shouldn't rely on it not rounding off. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html